# When price is 0 change add to cart button to "request quote"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

I have a product X in several sizes (added as variation products of the main product X). For small sizes the price is available and customers can shop it online. However, for large sizes of this product X, it is not shopable online. Therefore for some variations of this product X I would like to remove the add to cart button and change it to a button who goes to my "request a quote" page.

My idea was that if I set the variable product price to 0 that the add to cart button goes away and the "request a quote" button appears.

Any ideas on how to do this in woocommerce (php)?

Answer (score 2):

put this function in your function.php

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'requestQuote', 10, 2);

function requestQuote($price, $product) {
        if ( $price == wc_price( 0.00 ) ){

                 remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
      'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
                 return 'Request Quote';
        }


        else{
            return $price;}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This almost fixes it! However, it does not remove the add to cart  button. So now the customer can order the product for free. Any suggestions on how to include that?

Comment: @trika just edit my answer

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately the add to cart button does not go away..

Comment: it's seems you theme or plugin is using this hook try to increase the priority number 30

Comment: i will check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167276/discussion-between-trika-and-kashalo).

Answer (score 1):

you just need to make some condition with **if** function

```
    $price = 2000;
    $response = 'Add To Cart;
    if(size = XL)
    {
       $price = 0;
       $response = "You can Request another Size";
    }
```